# fadein fade out using libgdx , sin and java

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create a function that make fadein and fadeout.

I start using `Math.sin()` and `batch.setColor()` to fade the images to black, I don't know that this is the best approach but my idea is running a sin function.

I know that with sin function I can control my fadein/fideout time but I have 2 big problems:

1. I need to start counting when `senofloat == 0` and stop when its 1 or start on 1 and stop on 0 for fadeout,
2. I need control the number of times the cycles repeats, example 1 time for fade in 1 time for fade out

`tempo` is a global variable and

```
tempo = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

This is what I have on the render function:

```
float periudo=2;
float escala = 1;

senofloat = (float) (Math.sin(tempo*2*Math.PI/periudo)*(escala/2) + (escala/2));
batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, senofloat); 

tempo++;
```

Am I complicating this too much? Is there an easier approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Scene2D actions.

```
private Actor actionManager = new Actor(); //use a Stage instead if using one anyway
private final Color fadeColor = new Color ();
private static final Color FADED = new Color(1,1,1,0);

private void fadeOut (float duration){
    ColorAction colorAction = Actions.color(FADED, duration, Interpolation.sine);
    colorAction.setColor(fadeColor);
    actionManager.addAction(colorAction);
}

private void fadeIn (float duration){
    ColorAction colorAction = Actions.color(Color.WHITE, duration, Interpolation.sine);
    colorAction.setColor(fadeColor);
    actionManager.addAction(colorAction);
}

public void render (){
    //...

    actionManager.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    batch.setColor(fadeColor);
    //...
}
```

Call `fadeOut` or `fadeIn` to start a fade. You can change the Interpolation type to `Interpolation.fade` if you want. I think it looks better than sine for a color fade.

Answer (score 0):

Best option  and easier approach would be using [universal-tween-engine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/)

very easy to use and effective as it comes from Aurelien Ribon

Comment: Fix the link please.

Comment: Sorry, check now. :-)

Comment: I'm using tween engine now, after i saw some youtube tutorial, its a litle bit triky to add the library to the eclipse project but ists working and it seems to have a lot of potential. thanks all